# How Reparent component React and keep component instance and its state

Tags: reactjs

I am facing problem in React when we implemented move operation in our Dashboard that base on GridLayout.

In GridLayout in column we are rendering complex components (Complex DOM subtree) and we have no chance to change their behaviour. When we try to implement move operation and we moved column form one row to another react create new instances of moved component and we lost their state and component recreate itself and in our solution this operation is so expensive it is happening because we change component its parent. When we do this operation in the same row we are not changing component parent everting is fine.

After some research I have found only one solid solution that use

> ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer

I am afraid that there is not other solution how to change component its parent and keep component instance.

Good source of info about this problem is 
https://gist.github.com/chenglou/34b155691a6f58091953

RFC:
https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/34

and implementation of solution is from Leonardo Garcia Crespo here:
https://leoasis.github.io/posts/2017/06/26/reparenting-a-component/

I am afraid that solution from Leonardo use unstable react function.

And I am wondering if there is another solution how to change component parent and keep component instance and its state.

Thanks very much Ivan